# Get member list that don't have transaction in selected period #Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have member and transaction record. I need to generate a report that will list out member that don't have any transaction in selected period of times. For example: When I choose 6 month ago in the filter, Tableau will list out all member that don't have any transaction for the whole 6 months.

```
Member
------------------
MemberID Int
Name String


Transaction
------------------
TransID Int
TransDate Date
FK_MemberID Int
Amount Decimal
```

Does anyone have any knowledge to achieve this using tableau filter instead of at query level?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily create 'months_between' calculated member, then filter by this member:

[image]

Comment: [Tableau community](http://community.tableausoftware.com/welcome) is more active than stackoverflow for this kind of questions.